# Tkinter Screen Change as Altered Display - Easy way to rectify?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, raspberry-pi2

I understand that a few others have asked similar questions although i cant find any that match my specific issue so please be gentle.

My issue is every display i use results in my Tkinter display completely changing and im having to reposition and resize everything again through trial and error which is massively time consuming. Is there an easy way around this? I've used place and pixel sizes in the script so i think its everytime the resolution changes im having to start over.

Anyway I thought i set the resolution to the Rpi touchscreen and built the GUI to that. However, now i've bought the touchscreen the GUI isn't even close to fitting it.

I'm not that keen on having to resize and reposition everything again so if there is an easy way to achieve what i'm after i'd be grateful if someone could share it. If not, i'll just have to get on with it.

Cheers
chris

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using `place`. `place` should be avoided for exactly this reason. If you learn to use `grid` and `pack` properly, and do not call `pack_propagate(0)` or `grid_propagate(0)` unless you are certain it is the only solution to your problem, tkinter will do a fantastic job of adapting to different screen resolutions, font sizes, and user preferences.

In other words, the answer to "[is there] an easy way to achieve what I'm after" is "use `grid` and `pack`, and avoid `place`".

Comment: so it is a case of starting over regardless by the looks of things. thanks for the fast response

Comment: @chrisn89: it's hard to say without seeing your actual code, but generally speaking if you want the UI to respond properly to resolution changes and you're currently using `place`, you'll need to write the code that places the widgets on the screen. None of the other code will need to change.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to utilize the width and height aspects of your screen, and make your program relative to those instead of making everything fixed/static.

You can do this by calling `winfo_width()` or `winfo_height()` on your widget to get it's size. After you have this, instead of making an oval at 200 pixels if your screen is 400 pixels in width, you can make it relative, i.e. at width/2 (if you declare `winfo_width()`as a variable).

Comment: ill have  a go at that. Thanks for the fast response